# In Sitefinity, Sitemap generates wrong URLs

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-8

In my sitefinity application, when I generates sitemap it gets successfully generated but site map shows dual language prefix in URLs for all nodes.

Like a generated url node in my sitemap

```
   <url>    
    <loc>http://www.example.net/en/en/individual/customer- 
    service</loc>
    <priority>1</priority>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" 
    ref="http://www.example.net/en/en/individual/customer-service" />
     <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ar"
     ref="http://www.example.net/en/ar/individual/customer-service" />
     </url>

But I expect the generated url node like this

   <url>    
    <loc>http://www.example.net/en/individual/customer- 
    service</loc>
    <priority>1</priority>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" 
    ref="http://www.example.net/en/individual/customer-service" />
     <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ar"
     ref="http://www.example.net/ar/individual/customer-service" />
   </url>
```

Comment: Can you go to Administration > Settings > Advanced > System > Site Url Settings and see if there is anything there?

Comment: Where I found URLRulesClient and URLRulesServer with following rules

URLRulesClient

RegularExpressionFilter -->[^\p{L}\-\!\$\(\)\=\@\d_\'\.]+|\.+$
Replace with --> -
ToLower --> checked
Trim --> checked

URLRulesServer

RegularExpressionFilter -->[^\w\-\!\$\'\(\)\=\@\d_]+
Replace with --> -
ToLower --> checked
Trim --> unchecked

Comment: So nothing in the parent level, i.e. Site Url Settings?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev on parent level of "Site URL Settings" all fields are empty or unchecked

Comment: Very strange, do you have any custom URL strategies? This is under Administration > Settings > Advanced > Resources > UrlLocalizationStrategies

Comment: Yes! Under "SubFolderUrlLocalizationStrategy" I have added a parameter **Key** --> "includeSubfoderPrefixForDefaultLanguage" and **Value** --> "True".

Comment: That would explain it if there is a bug in the sitemap module. Try removing the parameter temporarily, restart the site and regenerate the sitemap to see if it fixes it.

Comment: Making this "includeSubfoderPrefixForDefaultLanguage" Value --> "False", generates fine URLs in sitemap . But I need to keep this value "True" . Is that any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what was discussed in the comments:

The issue is caused by the fact that the **SubFolderUrlLocalizationStrategy** had the following parameter: 
**includeSubfoderPrefixForDefaultLanguage** = True

Removing the parameter resolves the issue.

This seems to be a bug in the Sitemap module in that version of Sitefinity, as I haven't seen it in v.10.2 for instance.

One way to keep the parameter and overcome the issue is to subscribe to the **ISitemapGeneratorBeforeWriting** event and modify the sitemap entries before they are saved, e.g. Replace("/en/en/", "/en/")

This article shows how:
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-modify-the-entries-in-sitefinity-sitemap-using-SitemapGeneratorBeforeWriting-event

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bootstrapper.Initialized += Bootstrapper_Initialized;
}

void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
    {
        EventHub.Subscribe<ISitemapGeneratorBeforeWriting>(evt => SitemapGeneratorBeforeWritingHandler(evt));
    }
}

void SitemapGeneratorBeforeWritingHandler(ISitemapGeneratorBeforeWriting @event)
{
    var entries = @event.Entries;
    // CRUD operations over the sitemap entries goes here
}
```